# Ionic 2: Hide scroll-bar and keep scrolling

Tags: html, css, ionic2, scrollbar, ionic3

I just want to **hide** the scrollbar, in a page that needs scrolling.
I am using Ionic 2

My **not working** solution:

```
.scroll-content-bar{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

This solution hide the scroll-bar **but** makes the screen unscrollable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, changing natural behavior of the browser and expected user experience is a risky move.

However, if you still really really want to, I think your best bet is to fake it. In this case, setting `width` to 0 should be enough but I'm also changing background colors to be completely transparent.

```css
div{
  background: gray;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

p{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  border:none;
  width:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border:none;
  width:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border:none;
  width:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add below line to your css/scss file and it will work just fine.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add this to the .scss file.

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

To override in the whole app, add it to the app.scss file.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply this css, it working very well for me:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .scroll-content:not(.show-scrollbar) {
        margin-right: -17px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

you may improve the media query to attach only the desktop browser.