# Horizontal ion-scroll without scrollbar?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

**home.html**

```
 <ion-scroll  scrollX="true">
   <button ion-button color="danger" *ngFor="let item of allservices">
       <p>{{item.name}}</p>
   </button>
 </ion-scroll>
```

How to show ion-scroll without showing the scroll bar.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138740/ionic-2-hide-scroll-bar-and-keep-scrolling the answer use -webkit-* I don't think it's availlable on Anrdroid